# Picture alignent issue with firefox

Tags: html, css

Any idea why on my website the triangles look good on safari (they are aligned center horizontally), but on firefox they are floating to the right?

```
.triangle {
  display: block;
  margin: -80px auto 0;
  margin-bottom: 45px;
}
```

Safari: triangles are aligned to the center:

[image: Safari screenshot]

Firefox: triangles are aligned to the right:

[image: Firefox screenshot]

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a [**link to a site or an example**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it), if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the class `padding-onlytop-lg` from it's parent then change `.triangle` to:

```
.triangle {
    margin: 0 auto 45px;
    display: block;
}
```